# How do I close the timer channel?

Tags: go

I have a timer which is reset by certain events. A go function listens to the channel using range. How do I close the channel so that for loop exits?

```
func resetTimer(){
        if rf.electionTimer != nil {
             rf.electionTimer.Stop()
        }
}

rf.electionTimer = time.NewTimer(electionTime) 


for _ = range rf.electionTimer.C {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: time.Timer will only fire a single time, so there isn't really a need to range over it. Did you mean to use a time.Ticker?

Comment: @ardent an expired Timer can be reset, meaning it can in fact fire more than once (and unlike a Ticker, it can do it at irregular intervals, if the controlling code wants.)

Comment: I am using random intervals and using timer reset as hobbs mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a channel to signal when the loop should exit.

```
rf.done := make(chan struct{})
rf.electionTimer = time.NewTimer(electionTime) 

func stopTimer(){
    if rf.electionTimer != nil {
         rf.electionTimer.Stop()
         close(rf.done)
    }
}
```

Select on both the signal channel and the timer channel in a loop.  Break out of the loop when signal channel is closed.

```
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case t := <-rf.electionTimer.C:
            // Do something
        case <-rf.done:
            break loop
        }
    }
```

Note that it does not make sense to use a loop in the question or this answer if the application does not call [Reset](https://godoc.org/time#Timer.Reset) on the timer. If the timer is not reset, then only one value will be sent to the timer's channel.

Comment: It might be a little more efficient and make more sense for rf.done to be replaced with a simple `bool` rather than a `chan struct{}`.

Comment: @Acidic That introduces a data race when Stop and Reset are called from another goroutine.

Comment: Thanks, Cerise Limon. I am resetting the timer. I tried something similar to what you wrote but I used a channel of type bool and it blocked the channel when I tried rf.done <- true. Do you know why close works but not rf.done <- true doesn't?

Comment: @2ank3th Sending to a channel can work, but I cannot determine why it did not work for you without seeing more code.

Answer (score -1):

The channel from the [timer](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer) does not output a time several times. It will only output a time once after the timer has ended. Therefore, it is useless to use the `rf.electionTimer` in a `for` loop.

Try replacing your `for` loop with:

```
t := <-rf.electionTimer.C
// Do something with t
```

This will pause execution until the timer has stopped.

Keep in mind, using `rf.electionTimer.Stop()` will prevent the timer from ever ending and your `<-rf.electionTimer.C` line will freeze.

> How do I close the channel so that for loop exits?

To prevent the `<-rf.electionTimer.C` from preventing execution of code, I suggest you use:

```
rf.electionTimer.Reset(0)
```

Comment: My initial solution was to use t := <-rf.electionTimer.C but this creates a lot of goroutines that are frozen slowing down the process.

Comment: Per current docs:

"*The duration d must be greater than zero; if not, Reset will panic.*"

https://pkg.go.dev/time#Ticker.Reset